# What version of TortoiseSVN to install to be compatible with "format 29"?

Tags: svn

I just installed TortoiseSVN 1.8.10, just to see that there is an incompatibility with the format of the files, which is in "format 29". But what version of TortoiseSVN does this correspond to?

Answer (score 8):

There is the following correspondence:

- Version 1.0.x: Format 4
- Version 1.1.x: Format 4
- Version 1.2.x: Format 4
- Version 1.3.x: Format 4
- Version 1.4.x: Format 8
- Version 1.5.x: Format 9
- Version 1.6.x: Format 10
- Version 1.7.x: Format 29
- Version 1.8.x: Format 31